# How do I get the ARDepthData for a VNRecognizedObjectObservation?

Tags: ios, arkit, coreml, lidar

I'm prototyping an app where I use CoreML to identify an object. That gives me a bounding box for the object (which has 4 values all between 0 and 1). I'd like to use the *ARDepthData* I have access to thanks to having a phone with LiDAR to then measure the distance to that object.

The *CVPixelBuffer* of `sceneview.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage` has dimensions 1920 x 1440. The *CVPixelBuffer* of `sceneview.session.currentFrame?.sceneDepth.depthMap` has dimensions 256 x 192.

How do I convert the bounding box of the *VNRecognizedObjectObjservation* object to give me the depth data I need to estimate the distance to the object?

Answer (score 1):

Converting bounds of `Vision` requests can be tricky. Here is very helpful article on the subject:

https://machinethink.net/blog/bounding-boxes/

Also, I think new since the above article was written, there are some new helpful `Vision` functions such as `VNImageRectForNormalizedRect`.

```
let depthMapSize = depthMap.size
let boundingBox // your 0.0-1.0 bounds
let depthBounds = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(boundingBox, depthMap.width, depthMap.height)
```

It returns image coordinates projected from a rectangle in a normalized coordinate space (which is what you have from Vision).